# JACK JackRouter (and then?)

Tags: software, recording, ableton-live, vst, wiring

I'm using Jack 1.9.10.  I want to record system sound into Ableton, and don't want to plug a cable from line out to line in.

I start PortAudio, I turn on JACK Audio Connection Kit, it is already started.
(It's all set up for portaudio default default default.)

[image: Connections]

Ok, but now what?

In Ableton, I don't see any sound coming in via the 1/2 channels,

From the Docs:

> "You can route the output of ASIO applications into the inputs of
>   other ASIO applications (like a VST host application), and then
>   connect the audio output of that application to your system output (or
>   a combination of both)."

Ok, so system's capture_1, capture_2 is going into Ableton's 1 and 2, but I kind of want system's playback_1 and playback_2 to go into Ableton's 1 and 2?
That's not happening.

Ok I'm stuck.  Anyone got to this point and worked out the final step?

Answer (score 1):

I run the following command in the execute script after startup part of QJackCtl

```
pacmd load-module module-jack-source channels=2; pacmd load-module module-jack-sink channels=2;
pacmd set-default-sink "jack_out" && pacmd set-default-source "jack_in"
```

[image: add jack source and sink]
what it does is set up a jack source and sink and route your system audio through these

I end up with this
[image: jack routing]